# Colums.AddRange is to slow

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

This code takes 15 sec to execute:

```
this.gridView1.Columns.AddRange(Coloms.ToArray());//the number of Coloms is big
```

What can I do to speed it up?

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: Coloms is a lsit contains 200+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling visual updates.

```
this.gridControl1.BeginUpdate();
this.gridView1.Columns.AddRange(Coloms.ToArray())
this.gridControl1.EndUpdate();
```

Explanation from [the documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.BeginUpdate.method):

> After the BeginUpdate method has been called, the currently opened
>   Views are locked, and do not reflect any changes made to their
>   appearance settings. Calling the EndUpdate method unlocks and redraws
>   the Views.

Comment: Thanks very much.It worked. May I ask why add these two codes?